# Unique constraint validation now passes in Grails after migration from 2.2 to 2.3. FlushMode changed?

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

I am currently migrating a (larger) project from Grails 2.2.4 to 2.3.11. After a few changes and plugin upgrades I finally got the app running. But unfortunately, the tests are failing (most of them).

Most tests failed, because constraint validation failed, especially unique constraint validation. I verified this by creating a simple app with one domain class. The corresponding test passed in 2.2.4, but failed in 2.3.11. Here is my domain class:

```
class Car {
    String brand

    static constraints = {
         brand unique: true
    }
}
```

And here is the simple test (passes with Grails 2.2.4):

```
@TestFor(Car)
class CarTests {
    Car car = new Car("VW")
    car.save()

    car = new Car("VW")
    Assert.assertFalse(car.validate())
}
```

And if I change the test to:

```
@TestFor(Car)
class CarTests {
    Car car = new Car("VW")
    car.save(flush: true)  // added flushing

    //Car.findAll() instead of flushing a findBy will do it

    car = new Car("VW")
    Assert.assertFalse(car.validate())
}
```

The test now passes!

It seems, that the flush mode changed, but I can't find anything about it in Grails' release notes.

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Does anybody have an explanation (and a solution)? I am really worried about this, because this behavior has a great influence to the code base of the migrated application.

Comment: You're using unit test annotations, so flushing shouldn't affect anything in the unit test GORM impl. Are these integration tests? If so, don't use those annotations

Comment: Thanks, Burt. Yes, it's a unit test. I also tried this test with Grails 2.4.4 - with the same result. Only adding "flush: true" or any findBy-Method will do it.
I moved this test into the integration test section and removed the annotation. Then it is working without flushing or findByXXX. This seems to be different in Grails 2.2. So, I have to move most of the unit test and migrate them into integration tests...

Comment: How are you constructing your `Car` instance by passing a `String` to the constructor, shouldn't it be `new Car(brand: "VW")`?